# Manga about a guy and a girl who meet on a ship and both love sci-fi stories

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's about a guy who meets a girl on a ship. Both of them love sci-fi stories.
The girl tells the guy a story which might be real or might be not. The story is about a girl who has memories since the beginning of everything, but when she gives birth all these memories are transported to the child.

Does anyone know the name of the manga ...?

Comment: Sailing ship? Galley? Steamship? Spaceship? Are they lovers? Is he the father of her child? Memories transported how? Via floppy disk? Over cable? Through inheriting a book in which all the memories are hand written? By means of magic?

Comment: @Lexible they are strangers who meet on a ship and its very vague about how the memories are transported. This description was more than enough (refer to current answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like [*Omoide Emanon*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8343372-memories-of-emanon). ("Memories of Emanon")

> Based on the award-winning novel by Shinji Kajio, Memories of Emanon tells the story of a mysterious girl who holds a 3-billion-year old memory, dating back to the moment life first appeared on Earth.

Comment: This sounds like its certainly it, worth specifically stating that they meet on a ship, love sci fi stories and the girl tells the story which might or might not be real where she remembers everything